# Is there any way for retrieving featured or good articles list in structured format from Wikipedia?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am looking for an API or data point from which I can get the list of featured or good articles in structured format. The list of featured articles is present here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Featured_articles. But since it is in HTML manipulating the list is too tiresome as I am trying to classify the articles according to the categories. Is there some place where I can get a JSON/XML file of this list? Or any API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [categorymembers API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers) to fetch the list from [Category:Wikipedia featured articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wikipedia_featured_articles). That will be the list of talk pages, not the articles themselves, but it's just trivial text manipulation from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is information about Wikipeidia's API here:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page